# New relic alert on specific table/data

Tags: alert, monitoring, newrelic, health-monitoring, newrelic-platform

Good day everyone!

I would like to know if I can set up new relic alerts on a specific database or data. 
Example :

- Send out an alert at X intervals when the number of rows in Y table is greater than N
- Send out an alert Y table gets more than X inserts within N seconds

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported by New Relic's Alert Policies for an application at this time. Existing database monitoring plugins allow for some alerting thresholds. New Relic's MySQL plugin for example, allows for alerting on database connection count, replication lag, and reads/writes per second (these vary from plugin to plugin). However, these are not alerting on specific tables, but the overall database.

You may be able to create your own plugin that will alert on the thresholds you'd like to monitor. More info on creating a plugin can be found here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugins/developing-plugins